# Excel nested conditional formatting with indirect references

Tags: excel, logical-operators, conditional-formatting, excel-indirect

I am working on a MS Excel 2010 spreadsheet where the users want to have some combined conditional formatting. 
Individually the functions I want to apply are working correctly, i.e this condition formula works:

```
= INDIRECT( ADDRESS( IF( ISEVEN( ROW() ), ROW() - 1, ROW() ), 22) ) = "6 Monthly"
```

As does this:

```
= OR( COLUMN() = 25, COLUMN() = 28)
```

But combining the formulae fails to apply any format. No error is returned, but the highlighted area is unaffected on applying the condition:

```
AND( INDIRECT(ADDRESS(IF(ISEVEN(ROW()), ROW() - 1, ROW()), 22)) = "3 Monthly", OR( COLUMN() = 25, COLUMN() = 28) )
```

If I want the cells where both conditions are met to be highlighted, what should I enter as the formula?

Comment: I am applying this rule to the range $W$11:$AB$48, where every other cell in column 22 (V) has a string like "3 Monthly". The plan is that each cell where the corresponding cell of column 22 is "3 Monthly" AND the subject cell is in either column 25 (Y) or 28 (AB) should be highlighted. Can you tell me why the OR statement is not valid? It appeared to work, in that all cells in those columns were highlighted when I applied only that condition.

Comment: Couldn't see the forest for the trees... :)

Comment: It is an oddly behaving case. I would expect an error message if it were to fail, and if I enter the combined formula in the actual cell content the cells I wish to highlight calculate as '1'. It just won't come through as a conditional formatting formula for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),ROW()-1,ROW()),22))="3 Monthly")*(OR(COLUMN()=25, COLUMN()=28))
```

Comment: @pnuts, I have excel 2013, but this formula doesen't work for me as well `AND( INDIRECT(ADDRESS(IF(ISEVEN(ROW()), ROW() - 1, ROW()), 22)) = "3 Monthly", OR( COLUMN() = 25, COLUMN() = 28) )`, but `= INDIRECT( ADDRESS( IF( ISEVEN( ROW() ), ROW() - 1, ROW() ), 22) ) = "6 Monthly"` and `= OR( COLUMN() = 25, COLUMN() = 28)` work fine

Comment: @pnuts, does the formula `And(,)` works for you? I've no idea why it doesn't behave properly for me..

Comment: @pnuts, I have this result. Is it uncorrect? https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1ewb82k9jndbpk/image.JPG

Comment: Works for me (Excel 2010 btw @pnuts). In my case cells V27, 29 & 31 contain "3 Monthly" and cells Y27:Y32 & AB27:AB32 are now highlighted. Maybe Excel handles logical operators differently in conditional formatting or maybe the result of the AND() expression is not interpretet correctly as TRUE?

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional formatting formulas seem overly complex to me

Select `Y11:Y48` and then hold down CTRL key and also select `AB11:AB48` and apply the conditional formatting formula

`=$V11="3 Monthly"`

Format as required

That will highlight the column Y and AB cells in every row where col V = "3 Monthly" - isn't that the requirement?

Comment: Yep I might just go for your simpler option, though simoco's solution works and I still don't see why the admittedly over complicated formula didn't work.

Comment: I agree - it's difficult to seem why your version didn't work - you used =AND(condition1,condition2) whereas simoco's solution is =(condition1)*(condition2) - both of those would normally work but not here - I don't know the exact reason but probably because ROW() function returns an array like {25} rather than 25 - in some cases that isn't a problem but elsewhere it is. I imagine the multiplication using * forces an array to a number but AND doesn't do the same

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF`:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),ROW()-1, ROW()),22))="3 Monthly",OR(COLUMN()=25,COLUMN()=28),0)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. Still no effect. Also I'm not sure if `IF` is the right tool because I'm trying to highlight where both conditions are true simultaneously, not separately i.e the Intersection of the conditions rather than the Union.